# How to allow the user to press a button by both clicking on it or by pressing the space bar

Tags: javascript

I have created a device where the user can click on the on and off button to turn it on and off. I also want the user to be able to do the same by pressing the spacebar on the keyboard but am having some trouble. Also I'm new to javascript and this site so please forgive me for any mistakes.

```js
let buttons1=document.querySelectorAll(".col-6");
  for(let i=0; i<buttons1.length; i++){
   buttons1[i].onclick=function(){
   document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
   if(buttons1[i].innerHTML=='ON / OFF'||e.keyCode==32){
      ...rest of my code....
```

Comment: It's generally bad practice to place event listeners within event listeners. Consider changing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
let buttonState = false;
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(buttonState);

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {  // if space bar pressed
  if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.key === ' ') {
    toggleState();
  }
}

function toggleState () { // toggle button state
  buttonState = !buttonState;
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(buttonState);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="toggleState()">
Toggle On/Off
</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```